# Como puedo dejar un salto de linea en un alert?

Tags: javascript

El trabajo indica mostrar en un alert todos los integrantes de la familia pero no quiero que queden pegados uno al lado del otro. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
const nombre1 = prompt("Padre: ");
const nombre2 = prompt("Madre: ");
const nombre3 = prompt("Primer hijo: ");
const nombre4 = prompt("Segundo hijo: ");
const nombre5 = prompt("Tercer hijo: ");

const familia = nombre1 + nombre2 + nombre3 + nombre4 + nombre5;

alert("Los integrantes de la familia son: " + familia);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los saltos de linea
Intenta esto:

```
const nombre1 = prompt("Padre: ");
const nombre2 = prompt("Madre: ");
const nombre3 = prompt("Primer hijo: ");
const nombre4 = prompt("Segundo hijo: ");
const nombre5 = prompt("Tercer hijo: ");

// uno debajo de otro
const familia = "\n" + nombre1 + "\n" + nombre2 + "\n" + nombre3 + "\n"  + nombre4 + "\n" + nombre5;

alert("Los integrantes de la familia son: " + familia);
```

si quieres que aparezcan uno a lado de otro
Intenta esto:

```
const nombre1 = prompt("Padre: ");
    const nombre2 = prompt("Madre: ");
    const nombre3 = prompt("Primer hijo: ");
    const nombre4 = prompt("Segundo hijo: ");
    const nombre5 = prompt("Tercer hijo: ");
    
    // uno a lado de otro con espacios
    const familia = nombre1 + " " + nombre2 + " " + nombre3 + " "  + nombre4 + " " + nombre5;
    
    alert("Los integrantes de la familia son: " + familia);
```